# laravel testing error, no such file or directory

Tags: laravel, unit-testing, laravel-5, phpunit

I'm trying to create my first test in laravel.

```
    $random = str_random(12);
    $payload = [
        'name' => $random,
        'email' => $random .'@www.com',
        'password' => '123456',            

    ];

    $this->json('post', '/api/v1/register', $payload)
    ->assertStatus(200);
```

The method being called from this url `/api/v1/register` contains:

```
    $rules      = User::rules();
    $validation = \Validator::make( $this->input, $rules );

    if ( $validation->fails() ) {

        return true;
}else return true;
```

When I run the test it gives response status 500.

when I write  ( echo 1; ) above this line : 
        if ( $validation->fails() ) {
it outputs (1 ) plus the 500 status response

If I write `echo 1;` below the same line, nothing outputted, so that line the line producing the error.

I check laravel log file and this is the error:

> [2018-03-03 12:55:07] testing.ERROR: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such
>   file or directory {"exception":"[object] (PDOException(code: 2002):
>   SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory at
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/ws/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:67)

Note: calling the same URL from the browser or from a rest client works fine with no errors.

Answer (score 1):

Have you made any changes to your `phpunit.xml`? It sounds to me like your testing environment is looking for a database that is not there.

Comment: No I haven't made any change to it.
Does it require any edits?

Comment: I noticed that my php-cli doesn't have pdo-mysql

when I run php -m in terminal, I get a list of installed modules, I see in it ( pdo , pdo_sqlite) but no pdo_mysql

how can I install it for the php-cli ( it's already installed in the PHP CGI )

I'm running on fedora 27
@nvisser